# Proving that the limit of the Mandelbrot polynomial's co-efficients are the Catalan numbers.

Tags: sequences-and-series, fractals

According to [Donald D. Cross](http://cosinekitty.com/mandel_poly.html), the characteristic polynomial of the $n^{\mathrm{th}}$ iteration of the Mandelbrot function, $z_{n+1} = z_n^2 + c$ where $z_0 = 0$, gives the Catalan numbers as the polynomial coefficients as $n \to \infty$.

For example, expanding $z_3$ gives you the coefficients $\{1, 1, 2, 1\}$, or $1c^1 + 1c^2 + 2c^3 + 1c^4$. With each iteration, the detail of the Mandelbrot boundary contour gets more detailed. Images below describe this, with the contour plot $|f(z)| =2$:

This is the plot for iteration 4, $\{1, 1, 2, 5, 6, 6, 4, 1\}$:
[image: Iteration 4]

This is the plot for iteration 6, (see Cross' webpage for co-efficients):
[image: Iteration 6]

An issue arrives when you attempt to find the summation equivalent to having Catalan co-efficients:$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} C_n x^{n+1} = x \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} C_n x^n.$$

If you use the generating function for the Catalan co-efficents we get the function:
$\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}2$. Which very obviously is not a detailed representation of the Mandelbrot boundary contour. Image below:

[image: Catalan Generative Function]

This is obviously not the curve I am looking for, so what am I missing?

Comment: For each polynomial $z_n$ in the sequence, the number of terms matching the Catalan numbers is $n$ but the total number of terms is $2^{n  -  1}$.  So increasingly more of each polynomial is unrelated, so perhaps it isn't surprising that it doesn't converge to the simple function.

Comment: @Claude Is there a good way of determining the coefficients for the nth iteration of the Mandelbrot set, then? Something which is more efficient than $O(e^x)$?

Comment: http://www.mrob.com/pub/muency/laurentseries.html I think as $|w|\to 1+$ the Laurent series $\to$ the boundary of the Mandelbrot set. However, convergence is *very* slow.

Comment: @Claude This is a great response, could you possibly write it as an answer with a little more resolve so I could accept it? Thank you.

Comment: see also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/247038/can-we-define-the-mandelbrot-set-in-terms-of-the-generating-function-of-the-cata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Laurent series to approximate the equipotentials (level sets) of the Mandelbrot set [1]:

$$ \psi(w) = w + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{b_n}{w^n} $$

This is an explicit conformal map from the exterior of the unit disk to the exterior of the Mandelbrot set, with a recursive formula for the coefficients $b_n$.  See also OEIS [3](https://oeis.org/A054670), [4](https://oeis.org/A054671).

Setting $w = r e^{2 \pi i t}$ and letting $r \to 1$ from above, gives a parameterized family of curves $w_r(t)$ that might converge to the boundary of the Mandelbrot set (some things might obstruct this, I think convergence might depend on whether "all (including irrational) external rays land" or "Mandelbrot set is locally connected" or some such, I'm not sure..).

But, practically, it is *very* slow to converge, so other methods may be better.

[1]: http://www.mrob.com/pub/muency/laurentseries.html , which cites [2]

[2]: John H. Ewing and Glenn Schober, The area of the Mandelbrot set, Numer. Math., vol. 61 (1992), pages 59-72.