# Analytic continuation of mandelbrot function

Tags: fractals, analytic-continuation

Is that will work as analytic continuation for mandelbrot function, if not why?

Mandelbrot function can be defined with Catalan numbers as $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac {(2n-2)!}{(n-1)!(n)!}x^n$

From ([Infinite series as integral representation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4572175/infinite-series-as-integral-representation)) we know that $\sum_{k=x}^{\infty} f(k)=-2\pi \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac {F (x-1/2+it)}{(e^{\pi t}+e^{-\pi t})^2}dt$, which works for divergent series (and this is antiderivative without +C). So it should technically work.

I'm not saying that this is possible to give exact value of this integral, but at least we could count it by numerical methods

PS: If that will work, pls post image of this function in complex plane

Comment: What does it mean to analytically continue a *set*?

Comment: You right, terminologii of mandelbrot set is actualy use to call the limits of convergence. I will change it to mandelbrot function

Comment: It shouldn't "technically" work until we have a technical proof of your conjectural equation

Comment: It is proven in link. I mean, I hope it is sufficient proof. But I tried this in some divergent series and that works (but you have to be of choosing x which do not cross singularity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will work as an analytical continuation. Take
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{x^n(2n-2)!}{(n-1)!n!} $$
Then, rewriting as a contour integral it becomes
$$-\int_C \frac{\csc(\pi n)}{2i} x^n \frac{(2n-2)!}{(n-1)!n!} dn$$
Where $n!$ is of course the gamma function, but I've written it as the factorial to emphasize the correspondence between this integral and the original series. A linear contour from $1/2 < c < 1$ will work, in particular, we can compute the series as
$$-\int_{3/4 - i \infty}^{3/4 + i \infty}   \frac{\csc(\pi n)}{2i} x^n \frac{(2n-2)!}{(n-1)!n!} dn$$
For instance, here is what the function looks like along the real line, with the original function in blue and the continuation in orange. I suspect this integral doesn't converge for $x$ negative, so some more work might be required to get a continuation there (this may suggest there is a branch cut there by the way).
[image]

Looks like I was correct about that branch cut, the series evaluates to simply $-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1-4x}+\frac{1}{2}$. Which is of course the solution to $f(x) = f(x)^2 + x$ (i.e. the mandelbrot iteration).

Comment: Actualy my theorem is stronger than yours. If you take my integral and use integration by parts with changeing limits of integration, it will be the same. But I will get extra limits which correct my form to do not get divergent. Actualy you proved that I am right, but in different way so I will acept it anyway

Comment: @Wreior Would you mind posting your approach to this problem? I think there is a branch cut on this function, so I'm interested in how your theorem deals with that

Comment: Oh. By theorem my integral whould be convergent, but you would have to count it analyticly. Damn. I will think about it maybe there is a way

Comment: Wait just a minute. Mandelbrot function is just $-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1-4x}+\frac{1}{2}$? But it's set of convergence is fractal?

Comment: @Wreior The convergence set of the Mandelbrot function is not fractal. It looks like this question has been asked before, see here; https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3925497/proving-that-the-limit-of-the-mandelbrot-polynomials-co-efficients-are-the-cata